# Reload a div with dynamic content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The task is to reload a `list` div with all it's content.

The content is `space` and `foo`, which are generated also with javascript.

```
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div id="list">
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="space"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use

```
$("#list-wrapper").load(document.URL + " #list");
```

but that doesn't work properly - the reloaded `list` is empty:

```
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div id="list">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I tried

```
$("#list").load(document.URL + " #list");
```

Again, the new `list` is empty.

What's the way to do it?

**Edit** To make it clear the task. Imagine we manually made some changes on webpage, by opening Chrome Dev Tools and deleted 1 of 3 `foo`'s. And after that, we want that the script will reload the `list` div, to show all 3 `foo`'s, not 2.

Comment: Can you add more details? How are you loading it the first time?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to load the current `#list` which according to you, is empty.

Comment: @JesusAngulo The first time it is loaded not by me. It is a some kind of plugin for Chrome. The first time it is generated by Chrome itself, not by me.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to come to a proper answer. Do yo want to show the contents dynamically created or are you trying to load some data you have somewhere else.

Comment: @Franco. I'm Ipdated the post, see "Edit" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

`$.load` will do a HTTP request to the same URL and obtain the markup without any javascript being applied. Since you are saying that `#list` gets populated by javascript then it will be empty.

From jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution):

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a **selector expression appended to the URL**, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

There's an easy way to clone loaded elements `.clone`.

```
$('#list').clone().prop('id', '#list-wrapper').appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Ok, that is bring the light to the actual problem. Thanks fot that, upvoted. But what's the way to make it reload preperly?

Comment: I just added it, had a small mistake.

Comment: Hmm. That will create the second `list`, the exactly (not reloaded) copy of first. Firstly, why do I have 2 `lists` instead of one? And secondly, the second is not reloaded. I updated the post to make it clear the task. Anyway, the code you posted was helpful.

Comment: Well then the question now it's different. You want to call the javascript again by doing an AJAX request. I don't even know if Chrome Extensions will inject the javascript into the request, so it might not even work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just first empty the html of the div and then load the new html everytime.

```
$("#list").html( ).load(document.

   URL+ "#list");
```

There is gap in id selector in ur code(I.e. #list)